# Extract date from string by Regular expression

Tags: regex

I have different strings and want to extract date from that string. Is it possible???
Date pattern from strings are like

```
on 14th Nov. 2013  at  ||   on 30 Nov., 2012 at
on 24th Sept.2013      ||   on 7th – 9th Nov. 2012 at
on 22nd Sept. 2013.    ||   on 7th – 9th Nov. 2012  at 
on 16th -17th May 2013 at   ||  on 6th March, 2013
on 22nd March, 2013 in  ||  on 15th March 2013
on 15th March 2013
```

Comment: Do you tried anything already? What output do you expect?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please spend a minute reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
[0-9]{1,2}(?:st|th|nd)?\s*(?:[–-]\s*[0-9]{1,2}(?:st|th|nd)?)?\s+(?:Jan\.|Feb\.|March|April|May|Juny|July|Aug\.|Sept\.|Oct.|Nov\.|Dec\.),?\s*[0-9]{4}
```

however, I am not sure that month names are correctly shorten.